# SymPy rref() returning an identity matrix for a singular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy

```
import numpy
import sympy

n = 7
k = 3

X = numpy.random.randn(n,k)
Px = X@numpy.linalg.inv(numpy.transpose(X)@X)@numpy.transpose(X) #X(X'X)^(-1)X'

print(sympy.Matrix(Px).rref())
```

As you may verify yourself, Px is singular. However, sympy.rref() returns this:

> (Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

Why doesn't it return the real rref? I read somewhere I could pass simplify=True, however it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Not entirely sure it is such a good idea to freely mix floating point and computer algebra.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what that means. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have never seriously used sympy, so I may be wrong here, but I think in general a CAS like sympy is not optimized to deal with inaccurate numbers. So, because of the small inaccuracies in the floatig point arithmetic used to calculate and represent `X(X^t X)^-1 X^t`, technically, the result may have full rank even though it is "numerically singular". And while numerical software should be able to detect this (maybe subject to a tolerance parameter) the same may not be standard or even desirable for  computer algebra.

Comment: Hmm, that's annoying. Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: Can you prove that `Px` is singular? It may look singular - but you haven't shown it.

Comment: I mean I think it's because the rank of X is 3 and since Px is just a projection matrix onto the span of X, the rank of Px will also be 3. I don't know how I would do it formally but I don't think it matters. (For clarity: Px = X(X'X)^(-1)X'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [49]: Px                                                                     
Out[49]: 
array([[ 0.5418898 ,  0.44245552,  0.04973693, -0.06834885, -0.19086119,
        -0.07003176,  0.06325021],...
       [ 0.06325021, -0.11080081,  0.21656224, -0.07445145, -0.28634725,
         0.06648907,  0.19199866]])
In [50]: np.linalg.det(Px)                                                      
Out[50]: 2.141647537907433e-67
In [51]: np.linalg.inv(Px)                                                      
Out[51]: 
array([[-7.18788695e+15,  4.95655702e+15,  7.52738018e+15,
        -4.40875311e+15, -1.64015565e+16,  2.63785320e+15,
        -3.03465003e+16],
       [ 1.59176426e+16, ....
       [ 3.31636798e+16, -3.39094560e+16, -3.60287970e+16,
        -1.27160460e+16,  2.14338015e+16,  3.32345350e+15,
         3.60287970e+16]])
```

Your `Px` is close to singular, but not exactly so.  Contrast that with

```
In [52]: M = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)                                          
In [53]: np.linalg.det(M)                                                       
Out[53]: 0.0
In [55]: np.linalg.inv(M)                                                       
LinAlgError: Singular matrix

In [56]: sympy.Matrix(M).rref()                                                 
Out[56]: 
(Matrix([
 [1, 0, -1],
 [0, 1,  2],
 [0, 0,  0]]), (0, 1))
```

Numerically speaking your `Px` is not singular, just close:

```
In [57]: sympy.Matrix(Px).rref()                                                
Out[57]: 
(Matrix([
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

But with a custom `iszerofunc`:

```
In [58]: sympy.Matrix(Px).rref(iszerofunc=lambda x: abs(x)<1e-16)               
Out[58]: 
(Matrix([
 [1, 0, 0,  0.647383887198708, -1.91409951634531, -1.43377991000974,  0.578981680134581],
 [0, 1, 0, -0.839184067893959,  1.88998490600173,  1.43367640627271, -0.611620902311026],
 [0, 0, 1, -0.962221703397948, 0.203783478612254,  1.45929622452135,  0.404548167005728],
 [0, 0, 0,                  0,                 0,                 0,                  0],
 [0, 0, 0,                  0,                 0,                 0,                  0],
 [0, 0, 0,                  0,                 0,                 0,                  0],
 [0, 0, 0,                  0,                 0,                 0,                  0]]),
 (0, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Fantastic, this worked. I understand now your point about proving that it actually is singular. What exactly is it that the iszerofunc does?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `rref` method, but evidently zero valued elements are significant.  The docs mention something about pivoting, don't they?